# How do I remove gloss from an iPhone app icon?

Tags: iphone, flash, xcode, photoshop, flash-cs5

[Here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/general/remove-shine-gloss-effect-on-iphone-icon.html) is a tutorial that tells you how to remove the gloss on an app in xcode.  How can I do this in flash cs5?

If I can't, can I do something to the image in photoshop so that it looks like it has no gloss when the gloss is applied?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the xml that is generated with your swf go to the node     < InfoAdditions >

And add the following after

```
<![CDATA[ 

<key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key><true/>
```

before

```
 <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
```

Then when you compile, you icons will be without gloss

Answer (score 8):

For the plist, you should have the row Pratik mentions with all the necessary icons listed in the array.

Some of you will do this and still not have a retina display or gloss reflecting these changes.

In XCode 4.3.2 and possibly earlier versions, make sure you check the "Summary" tab in your project settings.  There you will find a section called "App Icons" that should show both your Icon.png and Icon@2x.png. **Make sure you have the "Prerendered Icon" box checked**.

Even after all this, you might not have the retina display working.  **Check the "Info" tab's "Custom iOS Target Properties" section.**

[image: This is where you may find that your plist hasn't updated your Icon files]

Make sure you delete the "Newstand Icons" section if you aren't going to use them or it will stop your app from passing validation when submitting to the AppStore.

Answer (score 1):

Set UIPrerenderedIcon to true in your plist. This may not work with older versions of iOS.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 5, there is an additional plist entry to be checked here:

Icon Files (iOS 5)
   -> Primary Icon
      -> Icon Already includes gloss effect