# How To Remove Gloss Effect From App Icon in iPhone/iPod5 devices?

Tags: icons, iphone-5

I am looking for a solution to remove the Gloss Effect from the App Icon for iPhone 5 devices.
I know this effect is provided by Apple by default, for disabling this effect we need to set a flag In `Info.plist`. This worked for me, for normal iPhone/iPod devices (non 4 inches). I have done each thing in the plist file. I have put in all the icon files needed too. I don't think there is a need for a separate icon file for 4 inch (iPhone 5/iPod) devices.

I have also tried these links, but my problem still exists.

[First Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727690/how-do-i-remove-gloss-from-an-iphone-app-icon)

[Second Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453680/how-to-remove-the-white-reflection-on-the-application-icon)

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Check you info.plist, and that you have selected the prerendered checkbox in your project description.  Delete the app on the iPhone5 that you are testing with and/or the iPhone simulator.  Make sure that you have included icons for all the device types you are deploying too.  Now deploy again and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Just clear your build and also delete app from iPhone simulator or from finder and run the app again. Also remove Icon already includes gloss effects to true under icons (iOS 5) in info.plst file.

Comment: ohhhhh that's the thing ..how can i missed that single steps.Well thanks to remind me...!!!